# Import geojson in NextJS

Tags: import, next.js, geojson

I'm trying to import a GeoJSON file on NextJS but it says:

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:8)
>
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

It worked fine when the project was in ReactJS with `create-react-app` but now that we migrate to NextJS it doesn't.

Maybe I need to configure some loaders on `next.config.js` but I don't know how to do it

Here is my `next.config.js`:

```
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css")
const withLess = require('@zeit/next-less');
const withImages = require('next-images')
module.exports = withCSS(withLess({
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ["@svgr/webpack"]
    });

    return config;
  },
  lessLoaderOptions: {
    javascriptEnabled: true,
  },
}));
```

Can someone help me achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay guys, I managed to do it!

I will try to explain what I wanted to accomplish, what was happening and what do I did.

I wanted to load a geojson data from a file into google maps api to load some layers, so I wanted to use it on `map.data.loadGeoJson(imported_file.geojson)`

First, I needed to make Nextjs load my file from the source so I installed `json-loader`

`npm i --save-dev json-loader`

And then added it to `next.config.js`

```
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css")
const withLess = require('@zeit/next-less');
const withImages = require('next-images')
module.exports = withCSS(withLess({
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ["@svgr/webpack"]
    });
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.geojson$/,
      use: ["json-loader"]
    });

    return config;
  },
  lessLoaderOptions: {
    javascriptEnabled: true,
  },
}));
```

And then, no more error message importing the geojson file!

But now, another problem. The layers didn't load! So I read Google Maps API and tried another method to load the geojson.

`map.data.addGeoJson(imported_file.geojson)`

And it worked! Hope it can help who is in trouble.